# WebSocket on proxy

Tags: firefox, proxy, websocket

Here's the issue, on Firefox 15 WebSocket like the [echo test](http://www.websocket.org/echo.html) will work on my computer at home but not at work. I was under the impression that WebSocket was designed to work with existing proxy settings.

Also its worth noting that at work the echo test is successful on Chrome but not Firefox, and that both browser are configured to use the system settings.

Firebug gives me the following error:

> Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at
>   wss://echo.websocket.org/?encoding=text.

What could be the cause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reasons in this case (secure WS on standard port 443) could be:

- proxy auth required
- invalid (i.e. self-signed) TLS cert

Comment: Given your WebSocket server is listening on `wss://bla.foo.com`, open the URL `https://bla.foo.com` in your browser at work (in a freshly started browser instance!). If that brings up an auth dialog, or an invalid cert dialog, thats a problem. If using Firefox and you get an invalid cert dialog, you can accept the cert, and subsequently stuff might work for WSS also. Reason is: WS is considered a "subresource" (like images within a HTML page), and browsers won't render any dialog for those.

Comment: If it works in Chrome, but not Firefox: watch out if the server cert is issued by an intermediate CA. Firefox is unable to fetch intermediate CA certs over network even when the root CA cert is installed. Chrome is able to fetch via net. Should that be the reason, you need to have a cert that includes all intermediate CA (and root) certs as well.